# Making ViewPager2 showing blank view

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I have a situation where I have multiple tabs as filters and upon clicking each tab the specific filter view is fetched and added to ViewPager2 for display.

These views internally gets updated whenever data set is changed and same views can be opened from certain other paces in app.

The issue I am facing with ViewPager2 are these:

1. Whenever the views gets updated clicking the tabs don't display updated view and even sometimes I get blank view.
2. When I have already opened the view from other place in app and then when I click the filters the view comes as blank.

I know viewpager2 does internal caching for which I have already set:

**mViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 1**

Is there a way I can ensure always fresh views are fetched by viewpager2 ?

Comment: Create a listener by using page change listener on view pager . Then you can provide the callback to child fragments to update the views .

Comment: Sorry, didn't get this correctly. Can you please elaborate a bit.